# Bind : Non-authenticated data: (Un)acceptable

Tags: bind

I am setting up a bind server (Centos 7) on my home network. A local bind server is installed, that relays requests to my Orange ISP box.
Works fine so far for direct lookups, but not reverse :

```
[root@marcel ~]# dig marcel.home

; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-38.el7_3.2 <<>> marcel.home
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 23565
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 13, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;marcel.home.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
**marcel.home.      0   IN  A   192.168.1.23**

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.           14235   IN  NS  k.root-servers.net.
.           14235   IN  NS  m.root-servers.net.
.           14235   IN  NS  h.root-servers.net.
.           14235   IN  NS  l.root-servers.net.
.           14235   IN  NS  b.root-servers.net.
.           14235   IN  NS  g.root-servers.net.
.           14235   IN  NS  f.root-servers.net.
.           14235   IN  NS  e.root-servers.net.
.           14235   IN  NS  d.root-servers.net.
.           14235   IN  NS  a.root-servers.net.
.           14235   IN  NS  j.root-servers.net.
.           14235   IN  NS  i.root-servers.net.
.           14235   IN  NS  c.root-servers.net.

;; Query time: 7 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: mar. févr. 21 10:06:07 CET 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 267

[root@marcel ~]# host 192.168.1.23
**Host 23.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)**
```

When I look at what is happening with tshark, I notice that my "dig" command is effectively transfered from 127.0.0.1 (my local server that runs bind) towards my box. On the other side, the corresponding "host" command is NOT forwarded.

Digging a bit, I inspected the two query responses. 
In the "dig" cases (OK), I could see "Non-authenticated data: Acceptable" sent back by my local bind server.
In the "host" case (NOK), it was set to Unacceptable.

Can someone enlight me to what this means and/or how to set it ? Can't find anything when googling...

Thxs !

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the reverse (aka in-addr.arpa) zone for the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet. This is done by an entry in the named.conf file and of course a zone file.

The entry in named.conf will look something like:

```
zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "<zone file directory>/1.168.192.rev";
        allow-query {any; };
        allow-update{none;};
};
```

In the directory where your zone files are you will then have a file "1.168.192.rev" that will look similar to:

```
$TTL 3D
@       IN      SOA     marcel.home.      root.marcel.home   (
                        2017052401      ; serial number
                        10800   ; refresh 3 hours
                        1800    ; retry 30 minutes
                        604800  ; Expire after 1 week
                        86400 ) ; minimum ttl 1 day
        IN      NS      marcel.home.
23.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.     IN      PTR     marcel.home.
```

Hope this helps.
Good luck!